# [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Expo.Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync')]

Tags: reactjs, facebook, react-native

I want to create a signUp with Facebook. The code should work so far. I compared it with different sources and they use it like I did.

```
    loginWithFacebook = async () => {
    const { type, token } = await Expo.Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(
        '449579609085368',
        { permissions: ['email', 'public_profile'] }
    );

    if (type === 'success') {
        const credentials = f.auth().FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token);
        f.auth.signInWithCredential(credentials).catch((error) => 'Error logging in Facebook', error);
    }
}
```

I am very happy about any kind of help.

Comment: You are probably importing Expo.Facebook wrongly. Maybe import it like this `import * as Facebook from 'expo-facebook';` and then use it like this `const { type, token } = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(...)` https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facebook/#facebookloginwithreadpermissionsasyncappid-options

Comment: I moved my comment to answer section, so it's easier to see for other people. @PascalMeger

Answer (score 2):

Just so it's easier to see for other people, I moved my answer in the comment here.

You are probably importing Expo.Facebook wrongly. Maybe import it like this

```
import * as Facebook from 'expo-facebook';
```

and then use it like this:

```
const { type, token } = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(
    '449579609085368',
    { permissions: ['email', 'public_profile'] }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

install expo-facebook by

```
expo install expo-facebook
```

then use this code

```
import * as Facebook from 'expo-facebook'; 

const login=async ()=>{

await Facebook.initializeAsync('<APP_ID>');

const { type, token } = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(
      { permissions:['public_profile', 'email'] },
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has been removed from Expo and moved to expo-facebook.

Follow this document https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facebook/